# Como funciona o mock em teste de integrações?

Tags: java, spring, junit, tdd

Como utilizar o mock nos meus testes de integrações?

Comment: Leia este artigo, é muito bom: http://www.devmedia.com.br/mocks-introducao-a-automatizacao-de-testes-com-mock-object/30641